# Replace/Add column values based on another column

Tags: r

I am creating three new columns and trying to fill them based on the values in two other columns. The new columns are "0-5", "5-15" and "15-30". First, I wanted to know whether or not the cells are within these ranges according to the columns upper and lower, so I created rules to fill them in with 'y' (for yes). Now, if there is a y present, I would like to replace that y with the corresponding number in the value column. I am stuck on this part. I am also wondering if there is an easier way to fill in the "0-5", "5-15", and "15-30" columns directly with the number in "value" based on the upper/lower columns without having to put in "y" first.

```
x               y        upper    lower   0-5  5-15  15-30   value 

378828.1    1682697.2       2       12     y     y    NA      4.04 
378828.1    1682697.2      12       37     NA    y     y      1.00
381625.6    1684852.5       0       63     y     y     y      1.96
388660.2    1704566.9       5       18     NA    y     y      2.65
```

Comment: `0-5` should be `y` for the fourth row as 5 is between 0 and 5.

Comment: Based on my rules, 0-5 goes up to but does not include 5

Comment: Will `upper` and `lower` always be integers? does `0-5` include 0?

Comment: Yes they will be, and yes it does

Comment: I have edited my answer

Answer (score 0):

We can accomplish this using the `dplyr` package as well as the `match` function:

```
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
    rowwise() %>%
    mutate(`0-5` = ifelse(any(match(lower:upper, 0:4)), value, NA),
           `5-15` = ifelse(any(match(lower:upper, 5:14)), value, NA),
           `15-30` = ifelse(any(match(lower:upper, 15:29)), value, NA))

         x       y upper lower value `0-5` `5-15` `15-30`
     <dbl>   <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>
1 378828.1 1682697     2    12  4.04  4.04   4.04      NA
2 378828.1 1682697    12    37  1.00    NA   1.00    1.00
3 381625.6 1684853     0    63  1.96  1.96   1.96    1.96
4 388660.2 1704567     5    18  2.65    NA   2.65    2.65
```

#### data

```
dat <- structure(list(x = c(378828.1, 378828.1, 381625.6, 388660.2), 
    y = c(1682697.2, 1682697.2, 1684852.5, 1704566.9), upper = c(2L, 
    12L, 0L, 5L), lower = c(12L, 37L, 63L, 18L), value = c(4.04, 
    1, 1.96, 2.65)), .Names = c("x", "y", "upper", "lower", "value"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```